# How can I reinstall Lion so that the "Welcome" movie plays at first boot?

Tags: macos, install

I'm preparing an old Macbook Pro for resale. I want to setup the Lion installation in a way so that the **[Welcome video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWnyvcIeWEU)** plays when the buyer boots the MBP for the first time.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't — sadly, **Lion has no welcome video!**

(However, you can reset a machine to the first-boot state by simply booting from the recovery partition, erasing the drive, and reinstalling Lion. See [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3708132?start=0&tstart=0) for more instructions.)

Comment: Aww :( This is so sad! Why would they do that?

Comment: Not *strictly speaking* true, if you are being pedantic (and I am)...  Right at the end of the install, after you have chosen your username, and keyboard, and wifi and all that, is a very short video on loop that describes the 2 finger scroll gesture, and requires you to scroll down and click a button to start using Mac OS X. :P

Comment: I agree... I was really disappointed when I first installed Lion. Perhaps it's to decrease the time until a machine is usable, or to make the experience [more consistent with iOS](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/07/04/so-there-is-an-os-x-lion-welcome-animation/).